# Как работать с DataGridView в С++/CLI?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Нужно выводить данные в `DataGridView`,как создать к примеру сетку `M` на `N` ?
И как получать доступ к ячейкам ?

Я добавил компонент на форму, далее, вроде нужно создать объект `DataGridView`, но в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) примера кода нет.

Comment: Видите, даже в документации ничего толком нет. Это вам прямое указание: переходите на C#. С вероятностью 99,(9)% гарантирую, что с вопросами написания GUI на C++/CLI вам никто не поможет. Никто!

Comment: к `ичейкам` никак, а к `ячейкам`...`datagridview->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value `

Comment: и, да, лучше переходить на на нормальный язык (C#, F#,...)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На нем студенты не так и редко пишут лабораторные работы, да и курсовые, так что 99,(9)% явный перебор! Другое дело, форум не подходящий, не тот контингент.

Comment: @Rou1997, да вы правы. Это вроде самый простой способ(вроде) добавить на форму пару кнопок и результат вычислений.